# Is it possible for a subclass to override the attributes of the base class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For example in in asp mvc,

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [DisplayName("Such a pretty name")]
    public virtual String TheName {get;set;}
}

public class SubModel : BaseModel
{
    [DisplayName("An even prettier name!")]
    public override string TheName {get;set;}
}
```

With the above would it be possible to get the Views that use SubModel to make use of its display name attribute and not the base model's?

When I pass submodel to a view, the label isn't using either of the displayname attributes, just the property name.

Comment: Duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555759/wondering-why-displayname-attribute-is-ignored-in-labelfor-on-an-overridden-prope,  you can certainly find some good information there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AttributeUsage.  IT should allow you to limit the scope of the attributes in your base class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class BaseClass
```

Comment: This only works for custom attributes, and cannot be used to limit the attributes of a class consuming unmodified attributes.